# Relation between Signal to Noise Ratio (SNR) and Transmission Bandwidth for FM signal

Tags: frequency, modulation, bandwidth, frequency-modulation

I was encountered by the below question ::

`The transmission bandwidth (BW) is doubled in an FM(Frequency Modulated) signal. So, the resultant SNR (Signal to Noise ratio is) ?`

The answer is given as `doubled -  SNR is directly proportional to (BW)^2`

How can we prove this?

Comment: You rather ask this question in the signal processing forum, you will probably have better answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**This**](http://www.silabs.com/Marcom%20Documents/Resources/FMTutorial.pdf) document entitled Frequency Modulation (FM) Tutorial by Lawrence Der, Ph.D. of Silicon Laboratories Inc. shows that: -

[image]

What the above is saying is that if FM deviation doubled (transmission band width doubled), SNR would increase 8 times. See also this from [**wiki**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_modulation): -

[image]

In your question there has to be some form of error because if SNR is "directly proportional to BW\$^2\$" and BW doubles then SNR must rise by 4.

> How can we prove this?

Basically, you can't prove something that is wrong without lying or some form of deception.

Comment: Lying, some form of deception, or starting from different assumptions.